# Playing soundcloud stream on multiple clients with meteor

Tags: meteor

I'm attempting to create a collaborative jukebox as a little project to learn Meteor, so apologies for this very high-level noob question.

I need to be able to call the soundcloud `SC.stream` (see https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#streaming) function on multiple clients. The template all clients are looking at is binded to a object that looks something like:

```
room: {
 title: "roomname"
 currentlyPlaying: { 
  trackName: "track name"
  trackStreamURL: "http://soundcloud/12345"
 }
}
```

I can't seem figure out a way so that when a client, say the admin, sets a new `currentlyPlaying` to trigger all client to run `SC.stream` and start the new song.

I'm just not sure what the right meteor features are to use in this scenario, so i'm not looking for a code solution exactly, just a point in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is SC.stream? Where's this code come from?

Comment: Sorry, re-read and realised it was ambiguous. It's from the Soundcloud API https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#streaming

Comment: Firstly work out how to play one song. Then to get it change when admin changes the currently playing song, you should use reactive variables in an autorun context that will rerun whenever the url for the song changes

Comment: That's awesome @EliezerSteinbock thanks!
I have it working on the client that actually kicks off the url change, just using a event like `click .song`. So for every other client should i use something like this http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun or http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar?

Comment: I think you need to store the data in a collection. No need for ReactiveVar here I think, but that is the right idea. Posted a full answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the currently playing url in a document in a collection. Then use `cursor.observe()` or `cursor.observeChanges()` on the client to watch the document with the url in it. Do this inside a `Tracker.autorun` in block.

When the url changes, stop playing the previous tune and start playing the new one.

See here for documentation on [cursor.observe()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe).